# A cleaner way to set a minimum amount in JS?

Tags: javascript

I'm calculating a fee based on a variable amount but the fee is based on a percentage of the amount with a set minimum of 600. I have the calculation working but wondered if there was a cleaner way to write it (`math.max`)?

```js
export const calculateFee = (amount) => {
    const fixedAddons = 80 + 21 + 113 + 87 + 136;
    let fee;

    // If less than 600
    if (amount * 0.002 + 30 < 600) {
        console.log('fee', fee);
        // Set a minimum fee of 600
        fee = 600 + fixedAddons;
    } else {
        fee = amount * 0.002 + 30 + fixedAddons;
    }

    return fee;
};
```

Comment: Questions about optimizing running code is better asked at [codereview.se]

Comment: BTW: *// If  amount is less than 285000* doesn't fit to the condition in the if statement

Comment: `return fixedAddons + Math.max(600, 30 + amount * 0.002)` ? `Math.max` returns whichever argument is greater

Comment: Thanks @Jens, I didn't realise there was a separate Code Review site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you can simply use Math.max(), which will return the larger of the values you provide. So change your function to:

```
export const calculateFee = (amount) => {
  const fixedAddons = 80 + 21 + 113 + 87 + 136;
  return Math.max(amount * 0.002 + 30, 600) + fixedAddons;
};
```

So if your fee calculation comes out to e.g. 500, you would end up with 600 (plus your fixed addons).

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify your code by using `Math.max()` to compare the result of your fee calculation with the minimum fee of 600.

```js
 const calculateFee = (amount) => {
    const fixedAddons = 80 + 21 + 113 + 87 + 136;
    let fee = amount * 0.002 + 30 + fixedAddons;
    fee = Math.max(fee, 600 + fixedAddons);
    return fee;
};
// example
console.log(calculateFee(1000))
```

Answer (score 1):

An one-liner:

```js
const calculateFee = amount => Math.max(amount * 0.002 + 30, 600) + 80 + 21 + 113 + 87 + 136;
console.log(calculateFee(1000))
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const calculateFee = (amount) => {
  const fixedAddons = 80 + 21 + 113 + 87 + 136;
  let fee;
  if (amount * 0.002 + 30 < 600) fee = 600 + fixedAddons;
  else fee = amount * 0.002 + 30 + fixedAddons;
  return fee;
}

console.log(calculateFee(1000))
```